# Buid Group video calling using WebRTC

Tags: webrtc, spring-websocket

**WebSocket**
Using WebRTC easy to implement peer to peer video calling. But how to implement group video calling using WebRTC and WebSocket in Spring Boot.?

```
                import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
                import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocket;
                import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketConfigurer;
                import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketHandlerRegistry;
                
                import com.call.event.ConnectionHandler;
                
                @Configuration
                @EnableWebSocket
                public class WebSocketConfiguration implements WebSocketConfigurer {
                
                    @Override
                    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
                        registry.addHandler(new ConnectionHandler(), "/call").setAllowedOrigins("*");
                    }
                }
```

**ConnectionHandler**
Here Socket Handler.We handle all user session and socket and payoads.

```
            import java.io.IOException;
            import java.util.List;
            import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;
                                    System.out.println("Got signal - " + message.getPayload());

            import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
            import org.springframework.web.socket.CloseStatus;
            import org.springframework.web.socket.TextMessage;
            import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketSession;
            import org.springframework.web.socket.handler.TextWebSocketHandler;
            
            @Component
            public class ConnectionHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {
                List<WebSocketSession>sessions = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
            
                @Override
                public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message)
                  throws InterruptedException, IOException {
                    System.out.println("Got signal - " + message.getPayload());
                    for (WebSocketSession webSocketSession : sessions) {
                        if (webSocketSession.isOpen() && !session.getId().equals(webSocketSession.getId())) {
                            webSocketSession.sendMessage(message);
                        }
                    }
                }
            
                @Override
                public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
                    sessions.add(session);
                    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("Connection opened!");
                    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                }
                @Override
                public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus status) throws Exception {
                    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("Connection Closed!");
                    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    sessions.add(session);
                }
            }
```

***WebRTC code***
Here WebRTC code for Peer to Peer connection. We using webRTC for getUserMedia and DataChanells.

```
        let peerConnection=null;
        let localVideo;
        let localStream;
        let videoTrack;
        let audioTrack;
        let stream;
        let signal;
        var signalingWebsocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/call");
        
        signalingWebsocket.onmessage = function(msg) {
            console.log("Got message", msg.data);
            signal = JSON.parse(msg.data);
            switch (signal.type) {
                 
                case "offer":
                    handleOffer(signal);
                    break;
                case "answer":
                    handleAnswer(signal);
                    break;
                // In local network, ICE candidates might not be generated.
                case "candidate":
                    handleCandidate(signal);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        };
        
        signalingWebsocket.onopen = init();
        
        
        function sendSignal(signal) {
            if (signalingWebsocket.readyState == 1) {
                signalingWebsocket.send(JSON.stringify(signal));
        
            }
        };
        
        /*
         * Initialize
         */
        function init() {
            console.log("Connected to signaling endpoint. Now initializing.");    
            preparePeerConnection();
            displayLocalStream(true);
        
        };
        
        /*
         * Prepare RTCPeerConnection & setup event handlers.
         */
        function preparePeerConnection() {
            
             // Using free public google STUN server.
            const configuration = {
                iceServers: [{
                    urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
                }]
            };
        
            // Prepare peer connection object
            peerConnection = new webkitRTCPeerConnection(configuration, {optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}]});
            peerConnection.onnegotiationneeded = async () => {
                console.log('onnegotiationneeded');
                sendOfferSignal();
               
            };
            peerConnection.onicecandidate = function(event) {
                if (event.candidate) {
                    sendSignal(event);
                }
            };
        
             peerConnection.addEventListener('track', displayRemoteStream);
        
        };
        
        async function displayLocalStream(firstTime) {
            console.log('Requesting local stream');
            localVideo = document.getElementById('localVideo');
            try {
                stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                    video: {
                        width: 500,
                        height: 300
                    },
                    audio: false
                });
                console.log('Received local stream');
                localVideo.srcObject = stream;
                localStream = stream;
                videoAudioTrackInfo(localStream);
                console.log(stream);
                // For first time, add local stream to peer connection.
                if (firstTime) {
                    setTimeout(
                        function() {
                            addLocalStreamToPeerConnection(localStream);
                        }, 2000);
                }
        
                // Send offer signal to signaling server endpoint.
                sendOfferSignal();
        
            } catch (e) {
                alert(`getUserMedia() error: ${e.name}`);
                throw e;
            }
            console.log('Start complete');
        }
        
        function videoAudioTrackInfo(localStream) {
            videoTrack = localStream.getVideoTracks();
            audioTrack = localStream.getAudioTracks();
            if (videoTrack.length > 0) {
                console.log(`Using video device: ${videoTrack[0].label}`);
            }
            if (audioTrack.length > 0) {
                console.log(`Using audio device: ${audioTrack[0].label}`);
            }
        }
        
        
        async function addLocalStreamToPeerConnection(localStream) {
            console.log('Starting addLocalStreamToPeerConnection');
            localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => peerConnection.addTrack(track, localStream));
            console.log('localStream tracks added');
        };
        
        
        function sendOfferSignal() {
            peerConnection.createOffer(function(offer) {
                sendSignal(offer);
                peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
            }, function(error) {
                alert("Error creating an offer");
            });
        };
        
        function handleOffer(offer) {
            peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer));
            peerConnection.createAnswer(function(answer) {
                peerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);
                sendSignal(answer);
            }, function(error) {
                alert("Error creating an answer");
            });
        };
        
        function handleAnswer(answer) {
            peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(answer));
            console.log("connection established successfully!!");
        };
        
        function handleCandidate(candidate) {
            alert("handleCandidate");
            peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate));
            
        };
        
        function displayRemoteStream(e) {
            console.log('displayRemoteStream');
            const remoteVideo = document.getElementById('remoteVideo');
            if (remoteVideo.srcObject !== e.streams[0]) {
                remoteVideo.srcObject = e.streams[0];
                console.log('pc2 received remote stream');
            }
        };
        
        
        function leaveMeeting() {
            let cnf=confirm("Are you sure for leave meeting!")
            if(cnf==true){
                console.log('Ending call');
                peerConnection.close();
                signalingWebsocket.close();
                window.location.href = '/';
            }else{
                console.log('you are in meeting....');
            }
        };
```